# Background Image not appearing on webpage

Tags: html, css

While working through a task on the web development course on codeacademy I have hit an issue where an image local on my machine doesn't show on the webpage. 
In the images folder, there are 4 images, 3 show on the page fine through the HTML code, but the last which is a being called through the CSS code doesn't show. I don't know why

I've tried different combinations of ./ or ../ before the resources folder.

Have also tried moving the image into the same folder as the CSS file.

In visual studio code, the URL in the code opens the correct image file.

```
.pageBanner{
    background-image: url("/resources/images/pattern.jpeg");
    color: khaki;
    font-size:  100px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;

}
```

When inspecting the site using developer tools its just states that the image could not be loaded.

Comment: Maybe you could check if your permissions are right?

Comment: replace your url with `background-image: url("@/resources/images/pattern.jpeg");` and add `background-size : cover`

Comment: Thanks guys, unfortunately, neither suggestion has worked so far

Comment: The issue is to do with the relative path to the file, I have no idea how to fix this, but I do now know what the problem is.